# Iterating through HTML table returns Uncaught TypeError: '0' property for undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've written a function that loops through every cell in an HTML table and upon matching a text pattern 'red.png' applies a jQuery method against another element on the page.

However, when executing said function I receive an

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

I originally thought this may be due to the table not being declared in the DOM on page execution, but have tested this by outputting the "table" variable below in console.log - I can see the table fine.

My code is below:

```
function poll() {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    //console.log(table);
    for (var i = 0, cell; table.cells[i]; i++) {
        if (cell[i].indexOf('red.png') != -1) {
            $("#tenantPreviewLive").css('background-color', '#FF0000');
            $("#maximiseLive").css('background-color', '#FF0000');
        }
    }
}
```

Any responses are appreciated!

Comment: Please provide the HTML, or even better a Fiddle working example

Comment: As a remark, If your table is created through PHP, it would be better to address this change in server-side code rather than parsing the HTML client-side... but that may be a completely useless remark depending on the context of your request.

Comment: @Bartdude, I am creating the table structure using a library called jsonTable - this is all carried out on the client side. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're never setting `cell` in your loop. You may have intended to do it in the condition (the middle bit). Separately, you're trying to use `indexOf` on an element; you probably meant to use its HTML:

```
function poll() {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    //console.log(table);
    for (var i = 0; cell = table.cells[i]; i++) {
    //              ^^^^^^^
        if (cell.innerHTML.indexOf('red.png') != -1) {
    //      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            $("#tenantPreviewLive").css('background-color', '#FF0000');
            $("#maximiseLive").css('background-color', '#FF0000');
        }
    }
}
```

I don't recommend using a loop in that form, but that's the minimal change.

Although [it doesn't look to me like table elements have a `cells` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#htmltableelement). They have [`rows`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#dom-table-rows), which in turn have [`cells`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#dom-tr-cells). So that would mean two loops (one of `table.rows` and another over each row's `cells`).

But as you're using jQuery, you could use `each`:

```
function poll() {
    $("#myTable td").each(function() {
        if (this.innerHTML.indexOf('red.png') != -1) {
            $("#tenantPreviewLive").css('background-color', '#FF0000');
            $("#maximiseLive").css('background-color', '#FF0000');
        }
    });
}
```

*(That assumes you don't have any tables within your #myTable.)*

You might also want to stop as of the first one you find:

```
function poll() {
    $("#myTable td").each(function() {
        if (this.innerHTML.indexOf('red.png') != -1) {
            $("#tenantPreviewLive").css('background-color', '#FF0000');
            $("#maximiseLive").css('background-color', '#FF0000');
            return false; // <==== Stops the `each` loop
        }
    });
}
```

Or possibly even use jQuery's `:contains` pseudo-selector:

```
function poll() {
    if ($("#myTable td:contains(red.png)").length > 0) {
        $("#tenantPreviewLive").css('background-color', '#FF0000');
        $("#maximiseLive").css('background-color', '#FF0000');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I've tried the original change and received the same error, so I had a look at your jQuery-based suggestion - should `cell` be defined before it's used in the if statement?

Comment: @lbrookes: Apologies, it should be `this` there, not `cell`. I've corrected it above.

Comment: @lbrookes: And the error probably relates to the `table` element not having a `cells` property, I've added an edit for that as well.